# General Solution of $y'(x)+p(x)e^{r(x) y(x)}=q(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form

I solved the case for the non-homogenous constant coefficients case and I wondered if there is a way to find a general solution to a non-constant coefficient case. I don't know how to approach this at all, the substitution $y(x)=\frac{\log (v(x))}{r(x)}$ gets problematic immediately.

Comment: I highly doubt one can find a general solution to this question. Even a much 'simpler' equations like $y' + y^3 = 1$ (which is separable) only has an implict solution and if we change the right hand side to $t$ then there is no known solution. The best you can hope for is a solution for very specific choices of $p,q,r$. Non-linear ODE's are nasty:)

Comment: @Winther For $r$ being constant it's way simpler. That's what causes most problems.

Comment: Actually one can set $q$ to zero (change $y \to y+ f$ and suitably choose $f$) and $p$ to $1$ or any other non-zero constant (further making suitable change of the independent variable). The real problem is thus to solve $y'=e^{ry}$.

Comment: Is there a problem integrating non-linear ode $y'(x)+p(x)e^{u(x)}=q(x),$ with ${r(x)\, y(x)}=u(x) ?$

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have tried thus far..

$$
y' + p(x)\mathrm{e}^{r(x)y} = q(x)
$$
lets set 
$$
y' - q(x) = v'\implies y =v +  \int q(x')dx' 
$$
therefore we obtain

$$
v' +p(x)\mathrm{e}^{r\left(v +  \int q(x')dx' \right)} = 0
$$
since $p(x)\mathrm{exp}(\int q(x')dx') = f(x)$ I can re-write the equation to yeild
$$
v' + \phi(x)\mathrm{e}^{rv} = 0
$$
where 
$$
\phi(x) = p(x)\mathrm{exp}(\int q(x')dx')
$$

this is where I become stuck, as setting $w = \mathrm{e}^{-rv}$

we find
$$
w' -\frac{r'}{r}w\ln(w) - r\phi = 0
$$

i will keep at it.

Comment: For $r$ being constant, we get $$u(x)=-\frac{\log (-(r\left (\int_1^x -\phi (x)\mathrm{d}x+c_1\right )))}{r}$$.

Comment: Yep that is right, though the integral for $\phi(x)$ may be intractable, due to $\mathrm{e}^{f(x)}$ term in $\phi(x)$. Though I will look further. Though, i am doubtful. But, I would glad to be proven wrong :)

Comment: For $f(x)$ being a polynomial(which is rather rare considering our $f$), we have the incomplete Gamma function.

Comment: This is where, nonlinear odes are trouble, in that generalizing relies on a specific form of the equation. But, hopefully you can gain some insights, and push on further with the particular form that you are interested in..who knows you may find a way to approach specfic family of nonlinear odes :).